# How to install Skype plugin into Pidgin on Linux?

Tags: linux-mint, skype, pidgin

Having installed the latest version of [Pidgin](https://pidgin.im/), how do I install the Skype plugin into Pidgin on Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin name is *`skypeweb`*.

Its Github page is https://github.com/EionRobb/skype4pidgin/tree/master/skypeweb

On most Linux distributions its compilation and installation should be simple, just follow this:

```
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev libjson-glib-dev libpurple-dev
git clone git://github.com/EionRobb/skype4pidgin.git
cd skype4pidgin/skypeweb
make
sudo make install
```

Tested and worked with Pidgin 2.10.12 and Skypeweb plugin 1.1.